# 8086 ALP String Display

Tags: x86-16

I have written a code for 8086 microprocessor for taking string from keyboard and displaying it as follows

```
Title Get the string from keyboard and display it

.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    str1 db 'Enter String ','$'
    str2 db 50 dup('$')
    str3 db 0dh, 0ah, '$'
.code

main proc
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    mov ah,09h     ; for displaying Enter String
    lea dx,str1
    int 21h


    mov ah,0ah      ; for taking i/p from keyboard
    lea dx,str2
    int 21h


    mov ah,09h  ; for displaying in new line
    lea dx,str3
    int 21h

    mov ah,09h          ; for displaying what you have entered
    lea dx,str2+2
    int 21h

    int 21h
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h
    main endp

end main
```

I don't understand why we have to give effective address of the string as str+2 to print the inputted string back ? If simply lea dx, str2 is used no string is displayed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first byte at STR2 should contain the maximum number of characters to read. The second byte should contain the number of characters already present. Because you initialized STR2 with 50 '$' characters and the ASCII value of '$' is 36 you effectively asked DOS to allow an input of 36 characters that are already there!
Better code `str2 db 50,0,50 dup (0)`
At the conclusion of this 'Buffered STDIN Input' the second byte will contain the number of characters that were read. I hope you see now why you need `lea dx,str2+2`. That's the address where the characters are.
Please note that with a first byte of 50 input is limited to 49 characters as DOS appends a terminating '$' character (Not included in the second byte).